# determining the staff's title when a certain transaction is done

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a transaction table with relevant data and username. and also, there is a another table that stores staff's title history by date. However, title history table doesnt have log of every single day.

Here is an example of my transaction table:

```
username    tran_date   amount
--------    ----------  ------
anderson    16/02/2019  1200
julie       17/02/2019  54000
williams    20/02/2019  32650
```

and staff's title log table:

```
username    date        title
--------    ----        ------
anderson    01/01/2019  assistant
anderson    06/04/2019  chief
williams    07/03/2019  chief
julie       15/02/2019  technician
julie       27/05/2019  chief technician
```

I would like to join with the title of staff on the closest day. as in;

```
username    tran_date   amount    title
--------    ----------  ------    ------
anderson    16/02/2019  1200      assistant
julie       17/02/2019  54000     technician
williams    20/02/2019  32650     chief
```

I have tried something blindly but nothing seems to logical :)

thanks for help!

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: In addition to @a_horse_with_no_name's comment, please also include any query attempt(s) you have made so far. Perhaps you are just missing a small detail.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mention about sql version. I added a tag, it is sql server management studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server, you would express this using `outer apply`:

```
select t.username, t.tran_date, l.title
from transactions t outer apply
     (select top (1) l.*
      from log_table l
      where l.username = t.username and l.date <= t.tran_date
      order by l.date desc
     ) l ;
```

`outer apply` is SQL Servers equivalent to `left join lateral`.

Comment: Thanks. it seems it worked, however with other clauses like lots of "when", query became complex. in addition, the main data that i worked on, is huge, so it took 23 minutes and still going :)

Comment: @Cemil . . . You want an index on `log_table(username, date)` for performance.  If you ask another question with information about sizing and performance (and you can reference this question), there might be other solutions.